# Java Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I am trying to append a string to print into a JTextArea, but some reason it comes up with this error "Non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context".

It should go to the database and get the data told to get.
This is the problem

```
jTextArea1.append(resultado);
```

Here is my current code

```
 package ft3;

 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;



public class JanelaIListarProdutos1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form JanelaIListarProdutos1
 */
public JanelaIListarProdutos1() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "LISTAGEM DE PRODUTOS", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.CENTER, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.TOP, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14))); // NOI18N

    jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
    jTextArea1.setRows(5);
    jTextArea1.addInputMethodListener(new java.awt.event.InputMethodListener() {
        public void caretPositionChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
        }
        public void inputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {
            jTextArea1InputMethodTextChanged(evt);
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 421, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(31, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 361, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jTextArea1InputMethodTextChanged(java.awt.event.InputMethodEvent evt) {                                                  
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                                 

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */



public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JanelaIListarProdutos1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JanelaIListarProdutos1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JanelaIListarProdutos1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(JanelaIListarProdutos1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>




    ligaBD ligacaoBD = new ligaBD();
    Connection con = ligacaoBD.obterLigacao();


    String query;
    Statement xpto;
    ClasseProduto classeproduto = null;

    try{
        xpto = con.createStatement();
        query = "SELECT codigo, nome, categoria, preco_s_iva, taxa_iva, preco_c_iva FROM produtos";
        ResultSet rs = xpto.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()){
            classeproduto = new ClasseProduto();
            classeproduto.setCodigo(rs.getInt("codigo"));
            classeproduto.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
            classeproduto.setCategoria(rs.getString("categoria"));
            classeproduto.setPreco_s_iva(rs.getDouble("preco_s_iva"));
            classeproduto.setTaxa_iva(rs.getDouble("taxa_iva"));
            classeproduto.setPreco_c_iva(rs.getDouble("preco_c_iva"));

            //int codigo = rs.getInt(1);
            //String nome = rs.getString(2);
            //String categoria = rs.getString(3);
            //Double preco_s_iva = rs.getDouble(4);
            //Double taxa_iva = rs.getDouble(5);
            //Double preco_c_iva = rs.getDouble(6);

           String resultado = "Codigo: "+classeproduto.getCodigo()+"\r\n"+"Nome: "+classeproduto.getNome()+"\r\n"+"Categoria: "+classeproduto.getCategoria()+"\r\n"+"Preco Sem IVA: "+classeproduto.getPreco_s_iva()+"\r\n"+"Taxa da IVA: "+classeproduto.getTaxa_iva()+"\r\n"+"Preco Com IVA: "+classeproduto.getPreco_c_iva();
            pesquisa jt = new pesquisa(); 
            jTextArea1.append(resultado);

           // System.out.println ("Codigo: "+classeproduto.getCodigo()+"\r\n"+"Nome: "+classeproduto.getNome()+"\r\n"+"Categoria: "+classeproduto.getCategoria()+"\r\n"+"Preco Sem IVA: "+classeproduto.getPreco_s_iva()+"\r\n"+"Taxa da IVA: "+classeproduto.getTaxa_iva()+"\r\n"+"Preco Com IVA: "+classeproduto.getPreco_c_iva());

        }




    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqle + "Erro no query");
        //System.out.println("Erro no query");
    }

    ligacaoBD.fecharligacao(con);



    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JanelaIListarProdutos1().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

Comment: The title says it all - you cannot reference a non-static object (access a variable or call a function) from a static function. Now, please post only the relevant piece of code and point out exactly where the error is. Dumping tons of code here expecting others to look up that needle in a haystack is a little disrespectful.

Comment: But how do I do that ?

Comment: I tried private static javax.swing.jTextArea jTextArea1;

Comment: The compiler tells you where the error is, right?

Comment: Yes, but im not been able to figure out how to fix it tried a few things

Comment: Define your `jtextArea1` as a static string like that, `private static javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;` and your `resultado` variable too.